# Minecraft Data pack bug, mobs are just floating items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I play on a Mac, I'm not sure if that matters since it worked every time up to this point. This is what's wrong, for example. I have installed a random datapack, a snow golem with a melon head instead of a pumpkin head. But if I install the data pack and make a melon golem, the head is instead of a melon block a item melon piece.

[image]

The same is with every other Datapack mob, for example, a copper golem Datapack (a vote mob from Minecraft live 2021). If I spawn a copper golem from the pack, it's just a floating walking copper ingot, as a item. Just a floating walking item, the same in every other datapack mob, just one or multiple floating walking items, random items. This annoys me very much and I don't know what to do. The datapacks don't come from the same person or download site. It's just every mob from datapacks. Can anyone please help me with this problem?

I have some photo's for more details. Can you please help me?

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't these datapacks come with a texture pack?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a texture pack that goes along with the datapack. You will have to download this separately. I am not sure where you downloaded this datapack from, so you will have to find the texture pack download yourself.

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you so much, i didn't know that you needed texture packs for datapacks..

Comment: @FinnStudios Only some datapacks require texture packs